# Is there a way to split JTextField into integer

Tags: java, swing, parsing, integer, jtextfield

I am currently making a calculator, which do the calculations for The Runge-Kutta method to solve differentialequation.
I want the user to input their differentialequation in a JTextField (DiffEqua), and then convert this from a String to Integer input, that can be used for calculations. i.e y+5*Math.sin(x)

The problem is how do I convert this String into a variable, that will contain, integers, x, y, sin, cos and tan.

I'ved tried to convert the whole String to integer, but I believe it has to be splitted or parsed somehow.

```
double i = Integer.parseInt(DiffEqua.getText());
```

The variable will be used in this context:

```
public void solve(double y, double h, int j, double i){      
xArray = new double[j];
yArray = new double[j];
for(int dex = 0; dex < j; dex++){
    F1 = h*f(x,y,i);
    F2 = h*f(x+h/2,y+F1/2,i);
    F3 = h*f(x+h/2,y+F2/2,i);
    F4 = h*f(x+h,y+F3,i);

    y = y + 1.0/6.0*(F1+2*F2+2*F3+F4);

    xArray[dex] = x;
    yArray[dex] = y;

    x = x + h;
  }   
}  
private double f(double x, double y, double i){
     return i; 
}
```

Comment: Integer can only store a single number, not an abstract mathematical expression. You need to parse it which is not a small feat. If you know the structure of the expression, it might be best to let the user fill-in just the values(in your case number 5). If not, you should look for some library which can parse it: http://mathparser.org/

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try to split the content of the JTextField at every comma or so, for example:

```
String[] numbers = DiffEqua.getText().split(",");
double[] numbersAsDouble = new double[strings.length];

for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
  numbersAsDouble[i] = Double.parseDouble(numbers[i].trim());
}
```

This requires the User to seperatethe numbers with commas in the TextField.

Comment: Is there a way to incorporate so it also counts -, +, x, y and then converts the array into an Double?

Answer (score -1):

There's plenty of methods you can use from the String class, just read Oracle docs about the String class at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html and maybe you'll find your happiness there.

Comment: This might have made for a good comment, but it is a poor answer.

Comment: why do u rate this answer as poor? is it bad to tell someone to read and expand his horizons about what is available out there? split is not the only method that can be used to solve this issue, so the best way to help is to suggest where to find more options and that's what  I have done.

Comment: *"is it bad to tell someone to read"* No, not at all. That would be the 'good comment' part. But it is not an answer as such.